# perl grep output from file

Tags: perl, grep

I am using grep to return the value for the first NAME found (which could vary from case to case) found and search for the value of NAME found. Also, would like to only have the output text after the last "/".

Example file containing

```
NAME = abc123
abc123 = /path/to/x456
```

Expected output:

```
x456
```

Code:

```
my $name = qx(grep -oP -m 1 "NAME = \\K(.*)" $file);
my $value = qx(grep -oP -m 1 "${name} = \\K(.*)" $file);
```

Comment: Why use system `grep` if this is inside a Perl program?  Open the file and read it, and extract what you need, with Perl in a Perl program.  Do you know how to open and read a file with Perl?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `qx` would be complicated.

```perl
use File::Basename     qw( basename );
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $file_qfn = "...";

my $name;
{
   my @cmd = ( "grep", "-oP", "-m", "1", '^NAME\s+=\s+\K(.*)', $file_qfn );
   my $cmd = shell_quote( @cmd );
   $name = qx($cmd);
   die "Can't spawn shell: $!\n" if $? == -1;
   die "Shell killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F )."\n" ) if $? & 0x7F;
   die "Shell exited with error ".( $? >> 8 )."\n" ) if $? >> 8;
   chomp( $name );
}

my $value;
{
   my $name_pat = quotemeta( $name );
   my @cmd = ( "grep", "-oP", "-m", "1", "^$name_pat\\s+=\\s+\\K(.*)", $file_qfn );
   my $cmd = shell_quote( @cmd );
   $value = qx($cmd);
   die "Can't spawn shell: $!\n" if $? == -1;
   die "Shell killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F )."\n" ) if $? & 0x7F;
   die "Shell exited with error ".( $? >> 8 )."\n" ) if $? >> 8;
   chomp( $value );
}

my $base = basename( $value );
```

---

We can avoid the shell and simplify things by using `capturex`.

```perl
use File::Basename      qw( basename );
use IPC::System::Simple qw( capturex );

my $file_qfn = "...";

my $name;
{
   my @cmd = ( "grep", "-oP", "-m", "1", '^NAME\s+=\s+\K(.*)', $file_qfn );
   $name = capturex( @cmd );
   chomp( $name );
}

my $value;
{
   my $name_pat = quotemeta( $name );
   my @cmd = ( "grep", "-oP", "-m", "1", "^$name_pat\\s+=\\s+\\K(.*)", $file_qfn );
   $value = capturex( @cmd );
   chomp( $value );
}

my $base = basename( $value );
```

---

But I think the idea of spawning children for this task is distasteful.

```perl
use File::Basename qw( basename );
use File::Slurper  qw( read_text );

my $file_qfn = "...";

my $file = read_text( $file_qfn );

my ( $name ) = $file =~ /^NAME\s+=\s+\K(.*)/m
   or die( "Can't find `NAME` field\n" );
my ( $value ) = $file =~ /^\Q$name\E\s+=\s+\K(.*)/m
   or die( "Can't find `$name` field\n" );

my $base = basename( $value );
```

---

I'd actually use something like the following:

```perl
use File::Basename qw( basename );

my $file_qfn = "...";

open( my $fh, '<', $file_qfn )
   or die( "Can't open file \"$file_qfn \": $!\n" );

my %data;
while ( <$fh> ) {
   chomp;
   my ( $k, $v ) = split( /\s+=\s+/, $_, 2 );
   $data{ $k } = $v;
}

defined( my $name = $data{ NAME } )
   or die( "Can't find `NAME` field\n" );
defined( my $value = $data{ $name } )
   or die( "Can't find `$name` field\n" );
my $base = basename( $value );
```